# Creating gradient descent for N features

Tags: python, machine-learning

With following code, I am facing an error as I print my shape of m in step gradient function. Its shape keeps on, changing as iterations increase, like first its 13, then 13,1 then 13,1,1. Why is this happening?

```
   import numpy as np
   data=np.genfromtxt("train.csv",delimiter=",")

   M=data.shape[0]
   N=data.shape[1]-1

   def new_step_gradient(data,learning_rate,m,c):
       m_slope=np.zeros(N)
       c_slope=0
       m=np.array(m)
       for i in range(M):
           x=data[i,0:N]
           y=data[i,N]
           #print(m.shape,x.shape)
           for j in range(N):
               m_slope[j]+=(-2/M)*(y-m.T.dot(x)-c)*x[j]
            
           c_slope+=(-2/M)*(y-m*x-c)
        
        
    
       new_m=m-learning_rate*m_slope
       new_c=c-learning_rate*c_slope
    
       return new_m,new_c

   def n_feature_gradient_descent(data,learning_rate,num_iterations):
       m=np.zeros(N)
       print(m.shape)
       c=0
       for i in range(num_iterations):
           *m,c=new_step_gradient(data,learning_rate,m,c)
        
       return m,c

   num_iterations=3
   learning_rate=0.0001
   *m,c=n_feature_gradient_descent(data,learning_rate,num_iterations)
   print(m,c)
```

Comment: Which function are you trying to optimize?

Comment: step gradient one ,actually i tried printing the shape of m ,its increasing in dimensions, idont know why thats happening,

Comment: error is in the line for j in range(N):
               m_slope[j]+=(-2/M)*(y-m.T.dot(x)-c)*x[j]